# Python: how shall I plot a figure which can zoom in/out freely

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use python to plot a figure which contains many data points; and I want to plot them all and zoom in to see each detail;
so how shall I plot this figure?

Comment: use Matplotlib plot (with Basemap) inside of a wxPython pane https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192991/python-and-interactive-zoom-plot-with-matplotlib

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Being pretentious adds nothing to the conversation. If you truly think his answer is "completely unclear", it'd be nice to provide him with tips to clarify it. The fact that something is provided by default is completely irrelevant; pretty much every answer you've written is with regards to default behavior of matplotlib. Practice what you preach.

Comment: I think the consensus here is that a question needs to have an underlying problem and that problem needs to become clear from the question. This is not the case here. The question is tagged with matplotlib, and matplotlib plots can be (almost) arbitrarily zoomed (within the limits that floating point precision allows). As such, there is no problem to be seen at all, hence the question is unclear. I guess the way to make this question clear was too obvious such that I didn't mention it before, but it is of course to stick to [ask] and thus provide a clear problem description.

Comment: @JaredWilber I do not understand what you mean by "Practice what you preach".

Comment: thanks everbody; and I find pyqt is alse can do this well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `plotly`.

Aesthetic, zoomable graphs are possible with few lines of code:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# Create random data with numpy
import numpy as np

N = 1000
random_x = np.random.randn(N)
random_y = np.random.randn(N)

# Create a trace
trace = go.Scatter(
    x = random_x,
    y = random_y,
    mode = 'markers'
)

data = [trace]

# Plot and embed in ipython notebook!
py.iplot(data, filename='basic-scatter')
```

The tutorial hosting the above code can be found [here](https://plot.ly/python/line-and-scatter/).

It has multiple examples of easy-to-create, beautiful plots. All with zoom functionality.